# How to handle "secondary" keys in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, foreign-keys

I'm evaluating using EF against an existing schema - the problem is that I can't work out how to set up associations between tables where the foreign key is NOT the primary key of the master table.

As an example, a `foo` may have many `bars` as defined like this (forgive the pseudocode):

```
table foo {
  int foo\_id pk,
  char(10) foo\_code,
  ...
}

table foobar {
  int bar\_id pk,
  char(10) bar\_foo\_code fk(foo.foo\_code),
  ...
}
```

What am I missing to be able to create the `foo_foobar` association, and hence a `Bars` navigation property on the `Foo` entity?

Comment: We had the same issues here and in the end had to make changes to our database so that foreign keys only pointed to primary keys. Is there no way you can change your database schema?

Comment: Unfortunately not - the schema's a nightmare for legacy reasons, and we've got to interoperate with it. Sucks, I know.

That being said, I HAVE seen cases where it's entirely correct to have both a primary key AND a separate (possibly composite) foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq to entities doesn't support Foreign Keys which don't point to the primary key of a table (see log message 3). Linq to entities will treat it as a normal field on a table. You won't be able to navigate to the entity it's linked to.

If you have an existing schema i'd recommend using the [edm generator](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/edm-tools-options-part-1-of-4.aspx) as this will create the EMDX file, code behind and even the view code (which can be very large). If your existing scheme is quite large Check out this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/11/24/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx), which explains how to deal with large schemas.

When you run the EDM Generator you'll find out all the things that are not supported.

Looking at a previous EDMGen2.exe log we got the following types of messages back:

1. The data type 'sql_variant' is not
   supported, the column 'ColumnName'
   in    table 'TableName' was
   excluded.
2. The table/view 'tableName' does not
   have a primary key defined. The key
   has been inferred and the definition
   was created as a read-only table/view
3. The relationship 'RelationshipName'
   has    columns that are not part of
   the key    of the table on the
   primary side of    the relationship
   which is not    supported, the
   relationship was    excluded.

We've also found that the Linq project actually crashed Visual Studio quite alot as the code file produced by EDM was well over 80 mb.